# Dynamic table name in cube.js generated sql queries

Tags: opensearch, cube.js

How can I dynamically change table name in the sql statements generated by cubejs?

I query open search via sql interface. Our index name consists of `name + date partition`, e.g. *transactions_2023_01_31*.

How can I append this date partition to the generated sql statements?

I know I can use the security context in the cube model but that looks dirty to me.

```js
cube(`Transactions`, {
 sql: `SELECT * FROM table_${SECURITY_CONTEXT.datepartition.unsafeValue()}
}
```

Opensearch allows to use [parameters](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/sql/sql-ppl-api/#using-parameters) to substitute `?` characters in the query, that works also for table names. Unfortunatelly cube.js opensearch driver uses it's own way of substitution:

```js
SqlString.format(query, values)
```

Is there another solution?